# How to register ILogger in Startup

Tags: azure-application-insights, .net-6.0, ilogger, asp.net-core-logging, .net-core-logging

I have a logging section in `json` settings:

```
{
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to register it in `Startup` so to be able to use in handlers.

So far I have tried various options but none of them work:

**Option 1**

```
    builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(); // returns error: IServicesCollection does not contain a definition for AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry
```

**Option 1 Update**

I added `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` to the project so `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry` is now available but still `ILogger` gives `null`.

**Option 2**

```
    builder.Services.AddLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.GetSection("logging"));
    }); // ILogger is null in handler
```

but can't find any information on my particular case

How to register `ILogger` in `Startup` that will keep using settings from my app json?

This is the handler I am using:

```
public class ExampleHandler : IRequestHandler<ExampleQuery, bool>
{
    private readonly ILogger _log;

    public ExampleHandler(ILogger log)
    {
        _log = log;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Handle(ExampleQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // _log is null here;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you installed [`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore)?

Comment: No because I couldn't find information what assembly `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry` resides in. I installed now (thanks) but `ILogger` still comes null to the handler.

Comment: I don't see any handlers shown in the question. =)

Comment: Well, I don't think you need to see the handlers. Basically once registered in the Startup logger should be available for handlers, functions, controller etc. to use, shouldn't it? I I added the handler to my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install [`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore) nuget package
2. Resolve typed logger:

```
public class ExampleHandler : IRequestHandler<ExampleQuery, bool>
{
    private readonly ILogger<ExampleHandler> _log;

    public ExampleHandler(ILogger<ExampleHandler> log)
    {
        _log = log;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!